# How do I change my password?

Tags: 9.10, password

How do I change my password for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to the command prompt and type

```
passwd
```

and follow the steps.

Comment: oh my pleasure. i'm glad you are using linux, and ubuntu for that matter. Believe me ubuntu is the best place to be at... i have been to debian-stable, testing, sid, even fedora, gentoo and arch in the end and finally back to be at ubuntu. Ubuntu has the best eco-system. No other linux leaves you that productive as ubuntu. I hope you enjoy your experience.

Answer (score 7):

System > Administration > Users and Groups

You'll see the option to change it there.

Answer (score 5):

In System -> Administration -> Users and Groups

Click on the Change... button

[image]

The next dialog will then prompt you for your old password and your new one:

[image]

Comment: +1 do not recommend the command line version except as an additional option or if it is vastly easier.